# How do I make a method parameter optional with user input? (C#)

Tags: c#, class, methods, parameters

I have an object called "operator" in C# with a method that takes two number inputs from a user and adds them together. However, I want to make the second parameter (2nd input) optional so that the default is "4" if the user doesn't enter a second number.

I know something's wrong because it just ends the program rather than using the default if the user enters just one number and hits enter when prompted for second input.

This solution is probably very obvious but it's eluding me.  I'd appreciate if someone would take a look at my code and see what I'm missing.

Thank you so much!

program code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Operator operatorObject = new Operator();
        Console.WriteLine("Pick a number:");
        int userValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Pick another number--optional");
        int userValue2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int result = operatorObject.operate(userValue, userValue2);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**class code:**

```
public class Operator
{
    public int operate(int data, int input=4)
    {
        return data + input;
    }           
}
```

UPDATE: Thank everyone for your answers!  I think I've got it working now, due to a combination of suggestions. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: are you sure?   userValue+userValue2   ı thing (userValue,UserValue2);

Comment: thank you, snn.  You are right about that error. I fixed it but it still does not allow default to work when a second input is not entered. It does fix the issue of adding the inputs when both are entered, though.

Comment: check if Console.ReadLine() is a number... your converting it to int without any checks.

Comment: Thank you, HimBromBeere.  When I run the program, I get this pop up that says "input string was not in a correct format" regarding this line:   int userValue2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  I think that's the problem, that it assumes the user will enter a value, and that it should be converting it. But I'm unsure how to fix that because I want the user to be able to enter an input if they want.  (and if not, 4 would be default)

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 cannot convert an empty string to a number. When you process user input expecting to get numbers as input, always use Int32.TryParse

Comment: Thank you Steve. I will try that

Comment: Either accept an answer or post an own one if none of the existing fully adresses your issue(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit to enter a value the input `Console.ReadLine` will return the empty string which surely can´t be converted to an integer.

So in order to enable the parameter to be omitted you need to indicate *if* the user entered anything at all:

```
int userValue2, userValue2;
int result;
Console.WriteLine("Pick a number:");
if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userValue))
    throw new ArgumentException("no valid number");

Console.WriteLine("Pick another number--optional");
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userValue2)
    result = operatorObject.operate(userValue, userValue2);
else
    result = operator.operate(userValue);
```

[`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) tries to parse the input provided by user and if parsing fails will return `false`. So this also works if user types something completely different like `"MyString"`.

Comment: Thank you Him!  This is just what I need

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling your method with both parameters. You should check whether to pass the second parameter. Something like follows:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Operator operatorObject = new Operator();
    Console.WriteLine("Pick a number:");
    int userValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Pick another number--optional");

    int userValue2;
    int result;
    if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userValue2))
    {
         result = operatorObject.operate(userValue,userValue2);
    } 
    else 
    {
         result = operatorObject.operate(userValue);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: How would this help?  `userValue2` is _always_ an `int`.  Also, do you know about optional parameters?

Comment: It's not an int if it is not entered. The main point I am making is that if you want to use the default for a parameter, you don't pass a value for it.

Comment: I edited the example to show the entire main method to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Operator operatorObject = new Operator();
    Console.WriteLine("Pick a number:");
    var val1 = Console.ReadLine();
    int userValue = 0;
    if (val1 != null && val1.Length > 0)
    {
        userValue = Convert.ToInt32(val1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Pick another number--optional");
    var val2 = Console.ReadLine();
    int userValue = 0;
    int userValue2 = 0;
    if (val2 != null && val2.Length > 0)
    {
        userValue2 = Convert.ToInt32(val2);
    }


    int result = operatorObject.operate(userValue, userValue2);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
public class Operator
{
    public int operate(int data, int input = 4)
    {
        return data + input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on version of .NET you can use  ? to check for nulls, but I tried to keep it simple

Comment: This will crash as well if the user presses enter without entering any number in the final Console.ReadLine

Comment: I imagine when you are just nailing enter, it gives "" as the value, which you then try to convert to int (hint Tryparse is your best friend here...)

Comment: why would that be @Steve?

Comment: Try to Convert.ToInt32 and empty string and look at the result (and you are asking three inputs here)

Comment: Now it is better, but still, you are defenseless if the user types "ABC" instead of a number. There is no way out. When you process user input expecting to get numbers you need to use the TryParse methods

Comment: This still doesn´t work when user does not enter any number for `uservalue2`, because an `int` will default to zero. So if `value2` is `null`,  `uservalue2` will be zero, instead of what OP wants (4).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Operator operatorObject = new Operator();
        Console.WriteLine("Pick a number:");
        int userValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Pick another number--optional");
        var userValue2IsValid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int userValue2);

        int result = 0;
        if (userValue2IsValid) {
            result = operatorObject.operate(userValue, userValue2);
        }
        else {
            result = operatorObject.operate(userValue);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Operator operatorObject = new Operator();
        Console.WriteLine("Pick a number:");

        int result = 0;

        int userValue;
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userValue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pick another number--optional");
            int userValue2;
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userValue2))
            {
                result = operatorObject.operate(userValue, userValue2);
            }
            else
            {
                result = operatorObject.operate(userValue);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Main(null);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

  ...
```

}

Comment: Thank you, Jeff. You are right about that error. I changed it but it still does not allow default to work when a second input is not entered. It does fix the issue of adding the inputs when both are entered, though.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff! This is perfect. It's just a little more advanced than what I'm working with so far since I've not yet used Parse, but it serves its purpose and helps me understand! Thanks again