# If an user does not input a local variable how do i define it using other variables? C#

Tags: c#

Let me explain.
I am a high school student with not a lot of expirience programming in C#, we have an asigment to make a geometry calculator i got a triangular pyramid, but thats beside the point. The calculator is suposed to get an imput from the user and then with that given data calculate the surface and the volume.

```
               double a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
               double h = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
               double H = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
               double area = Math.Pow(a, 2) * Math.Sqrt(3) / 4 + 3 * a * h / 2;
                double volume = Math.Pow(a, 2) * Math.Sqrt(3) * H / 12;
                Console.WriteLine(volume);
               Console.WriteLine(area);
               Console.ReadLine();
```

Now thats easy for me , but a problem arises when the user does not know the value of one of the variables for example the hight.In such a  instance the calculator is suposed to calculate it using the other two local variables.

```
double h = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
double h = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(a * Math.Sqrt(3) / 3, 2) + Math.Pow(H));
```

I know i know you cant do this but i coudn't find anything on the internet, so i beg you for help since this is 20% of my grade. 
And if this can't be done do you have any other sugestions.

P.s. Sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: Instead of writing a Console application, write a simple Windows Forms app. Put text box controls on the form for the possible user inputs as well as a button marked "Calculate" and another marked "Clear". Let the user enter some data and press the Calculate button. When that happens, look at what data has been entered (and what's missing) and calculate what's missing

Comment: Have the user enter a **sentinel** value to indicate that they don't know something.  Use a value that doesn't make sense for the problem.  In this case, 0 (zero) or negative one (-1) would work well.  Then simply use some `if` statements to see which variable has the sentinel value and calculate accordingly...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a method parameter optional with user input? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616118/how-do-i-make-a-method-parameter-optional-with-user-input-c)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple to accomplish. Not having a variable means that you'll have a different formula/calculation depending on the missing variable, you can do this with `if` conditionals.

```
   //Read them in as strings if you want to check if they're "_blank_", convert them 
     later.
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        string h = Console.ReadLine();
        string H = Console.ReadLine();

        double area = 0;
        double volume = 0;
    
        if(a == "") //If it's blank, no entry do this code. 
        {
                  //This is how I'd convert it, just a little less pretty for the sake
                  //of understanding for you. You'd need to do this in every if block.
                  double returnedDoubleh = ConvertToDouble(h);
                  double returnedDoubleH = ConvertToDouble(H);
                  //Have your formula if `a` is blank.
        }
        else if (h == "")
        {
                  double returnedDoubleA = ConvertToDouble(a);
                  double returnedDoubleH = ConvertToDouble(H);
                  //Have your formula if `h` is blank.
        }
        else if (H == "")
        {
                  double returnedDoubleA = ConvertToDouble(a);
                  double returnedDoubleh = ConvertToDouble(h);
                  //Have your formula if `H` is blank.
        }
        else //This is if none are blank OR More than one is blank which would crash if 
                more than one is blank.. 
        {
                        area = Math.Pow(a, 2) * Math.Sqrt(3) / 4 + 3 * a * h / 2;
                        volume = Math.Pow(a, 2) * Math.Sqrt(3) * H / 12;        
        }

                       Console.WriteLine(volume);
                       Console.WriteLine(area);
                       Console.ReadLine();
```

## Example Function to convert your string values.

```
public static double ConvertToDouble(string nonConverted)
        {
            double converted;
            while (!double.TryParse(nonConverted, out converted) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nonConverted))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine($"INVALID RESPONSE\n\r" +
                    $"\n\rTry Again");
                nonConverted = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            return converted;
        }
```

In your conditionals you can also use a "Variable" so instead of saying `if(a == "")` you could do something like `if(a == "x")`

Comment: When I try and add one of the local variables into the formula it doesn't convert them to double but keeps them as strings don't know why.